# ICMP echo-reply packets with a much lower TTL (-190) than ICMP time-exceeded packets

Tags: ping, networking, icmp, ttl

When I **ping** the **last three hops** of a traceroute path to facebook.com from my location, the ICMP echo-reply packets I get back all have a **TTL** of respectively **58, 57 and 56**. The hops in question are the 6th, 7th and 8th hops from my machine.

On the other hand, the **TTLs of ICMP time-exceeded messages** for packets expiring on those three hops, have all a reasonable value: 246, 248, 249.

Now, the **return path** might well not be the same as the **forward path** and it might not be the same for ICMP messages of different types.

But where could such a difference come from?  A 200-hop **cycle** along path? Or ICMP echo-reply packets being generated with a low TTL (much lower than 255: does this even happen?)?

Comment: I suggest to modify your title to "Why forward ICMP packets have lower TTL than return packets ?"  It's more accurate I think

Comment: Yeah, good point. Done :)

Comment: Doesn't it make sense that "time-excedded" messages uses the maximum TTL possible ? they are made to tell you your echo-request had a too low TTL after all

Comment: Yes, sure. Time-exceeded messages have exactly the TTL I would expect from any other packet coming from their respective source. What I can't explain is why echo-replies have such a low value.

Comment: Maybe echo-replies use the same TTL as echo-request which have 64 by default on most "ping" implementations (wild guess)

Comment: YES! That's the reason. I did some tcpdumping and found out that all my echo-request messages (on linux) leave my host with TTL=64. The hops before the ones I mentioned in my messages all replied with an ICMP echo-reply originally with TTL=255, but now after some random pinging I found out that most hosts actually reply with an echo-reply with TTL=64. Thanks! Problem solved :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by the user kwaio, the default (or a common) TTL value to use when generating **ICMP echo-request** and **echo-reply** packets is `64`.

In my case, the first routers along my selected path responded with an echo-reply message with TTL=255 (at the source), while the last ones with TTL=64.

It appears instead that **ICMP time-exceeded** messages were created in all cases with a TTL of 255.

After some digging, I found out that different vendors and different OS's adopt different initial TTLs for different protocols: binbert.com/blog/2009/12/default-time-to-live-ttl-values

An interesting implication of this is that you can take identify the manifacturer of a given router by letting a packet expire on it and by sending it a ping. More details here:
[TTL-based Fingerprinting and MPLS](http://www-r2.u-strasbg.fr/~merindol/download/Vanaubel-TTL.pdf) and the full article: ["Network Fingerprinting: TTL-Based Router Signatures"](http://orbi.ulg.ac.be/handle/2268/154575).

Comment: You may mark the answer as accepted yourself =) (and i would suggest removing your comment to add it in the answer by editing it)